# PHP or MySQL fault?

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am doing infinite curl via `Webserver API` to grep `millions of data` remotely. (Using PHP & MySQL)

The mechanism behind is that it went through for a few tables via the API and every round trip query numbers of data(as below trial) to store into local server, sleep for few seconds(as stated below) and redo the interval. So far all the process doesn't turn in a good result. It is either slow or failed.

What is exactly the show stoppers here? How can I smoothly execute this curl within a reasonable time frame?

**Trial based as below:-**

*s as in seconds.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| No. of Data Query |  Sleep  |   Results                                                |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   100 per trip    |    5s   |    Smooth but slow (imagine, few millions of data to DL  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1000 per trip    |    2s   |    After a few intervals it stopped for unknown reason.. |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 10000 per trip    |    2s   |    After a few intervals it stopped for unknown reason...|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 10000 per trip    |    5s   |    After a few intervals it stopped for unknown reason...|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Codes :-**

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // We will set php execution time to unlimited

include_once __DIR__ . "/../bm/custom/xxx/xxx.php";
include_once  __DIR__ . "/../bm/util/xxx.php";
use bm\custom\xxx\xxx;
use bm\util\xxx;

$uclim = new xxx();
$client = new xxxx();

// Database Credentials
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxxx';
$db = 'xxxx';
$db_conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

// Initialize result variable to be null
$result = null;

$allSensors = array(
    'SENSOR_xxx'=>'xxxx',
    'SENSOR_xxxa'=>'xxxx',
    'SENSOR_xxxb'=>'xxxx',
    'SENSOR_xxxc'=>'xxxx',
    'SENSOR_xxxd'=>'xxxx',
    'SENSOR_xxxe'=>'xxxx',
    'SENSOR_xxxf'=>'xxxx',
    'SENSOR_xxxg'=>'xxxx'
);

$configs = array(
        'API_KEY'=>'xxxxxx',
        'HOST'=>'https://xxx',
        'API_STR'=>'xxxx',
        'TYPE_STR_ORGANIZATION_LIST'=>'xxxx',
        'TYPE_STR_DATASTORE_SEARCH'=>'xxxx',
        'TYPE_STR'=>'xxxx' 
);

/* Here we specified which data to acquired */
foreach($allSensors as $tableName=>$tableResourceId){

 $url = null; 
 $offset = 0;

 while(true){ // Here we start infinite loop until the end of the results

     $data = array(
        'resource_id'=>$tableResourceId,
        'limit'=>1000, // Numbers of Query each interval.
        'offset'=>$offset
     );

     //if(empty($result->result->_links->next)){
      $url = $configs['HOST'] . $configs['API_STR'] . $configs['TYPE_STR'];
     //}

     $data = json_encode($data);

     $headers_in = array(
        'Authorization: ' . $configs['API_KEY'],
        'Content-Type: application/json', 
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
     );


     $result = $client->curlUsingPost($url, $data, $headers_in);
     $result = json_decode($result);


     if( !empty($result->result->_links->next) && empty($result->result->records)){ break; } // Here we check if empty records sent from the api then we will break the loops


     // We gather all the fields from the Sensors for database table creation
     if(!empty($result->result->fields)){
     $allFields = null;
     $i = 0;
     $len = count($result->result->fields);
     $checkPriKey = 0;
     foreach($result->result->fields as $fieldName){
        if($fieldName->id == "_id"){
          $checkPriKey = 1;
        }

        if($i == $len - 1){ // To check if it is last row
         $allFields .= $fieldName->id." ".$fieldName->type.", PRIMARY KEY (_id)";
        }else{
         $allFields .= $fieldName->id." ".$fieldName->type.",";
        }
        $i++;
     }

     // Merge the collected fields name into sql format
     $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName ( $allFields )";
     $db_conn->query($sql);
     }

     // We gather fieldnames pattern from records
     if(!empty($result->result->records)){
       $recordsField = array();
       $sqlTableField = null;
       $o = 0;
       $fieldsLen = count((array)$result->result->records[0]);
       foreach($result->result->records[0] as $key=>$value){
          array_push($recordsField, $key);
          if($o == $fieldsLen - 1){
            $sqlTableField .= $key;
          }else{
            $sqlTableField .= $key.",";
          }
          $o++;
       }

       // We will insert values from records into table.
       $multipleInsert = null;
       $recordCounter = 0;
       $recordLen = count((array)$result->result->records);
       foreach($result->result->records as $key=>$record){
          $insertStr = null;
          $u = 0;
          $recordsLen = count($recordsField);
          foreach($recordsField as $fieldName){
            if($u == $recordsLen - 1){
              $insertStr .= '"'.$record->$fieldName.'"';
            }else{
              $insertStr .= '"'.$record->$fieldName.'",';
            }
            $u++;
          }
        if($recordCounter == $recordLen - 1){
         $multipleInsert .= "(".$insertStr.");";
        }else{
         $multipleInsert .= "(".$insertStr."),";
        }
        $recordCounter++;
       }

       // Insert api requested value into DB 
       $compiledSql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($sqlTableField) VALUES $multipleInsert";
       $db_conn->query($compiledSql);

     } // End of gather fieldnames pattern from records

   //Increament offset value
   $offset = $offset + 1000;

 } // End of infinite while loop
}


?>
```

*PS: Please let me know if the above question need more elaboration.*

Comment: Are you just asking us to guess??? Or you actually need help and have necessary actionable info?

Comment: You want us to debug without seeing code?

Comment: Why does it need to sleep anyway? Usually when I do something like that I use `curl_multi_*` to fetch non stop with 16 parallel instances of cURL at once.

Comment: The codes are fine as it store into the db properly. But the query through web api failed in either slow or unknown reason. How can I drill down to the reasoning and causes?

Comment: You can start by showing us what you are doing. There can be lots of causes for this, inefficient SQL Query, misuse of cURL, timeouts, error reporting interfering with output... theres no way we can tell without seeing it.

Comment: @Havenard I suspect that the request to the remote server too fast and it blocks my ip. That's why I put it sleep for few seconds.

Comment: okay hold on, let me post the codes...

Comment: You can read the API documentation to learn if theres a limit. It may also be dropping your connection simply because its overloaded or under DDoS attack. You have to write your application to handle these cases.

Comment: @Havenard I had added in the codes. Kindly review.

Comment: @Havenard I read through the API, it doesn't include the part of limitation :/